# How should I write an MDX Filter statement with multiple OR conditions efficiently?

Tags: mdx

In SQL you can compare a field against a set in the form

```
[Foo] In {"Bar1", "Bar2", ... , "BarN"}
```

However I'm having trouble working out how to move a filter expression into something like this. That is, for now, I end up with:

```
Filter(
    [MyHierarchy].[Foo].Members,
    [MyHierarchy].CurentMember.Name = "1"
    OR [MyHierarchy].CurentMember.Name = "2"
    ...
    OR [MyHierarchy].CurentMember.Name = "N"
)
```

Since I have 20-30 comparisons, and a moderate chance of the heirarchy name changing, I'd much rather maintain a set and a hierarchy name than a long expression. Is there any way to accomplish this?

Worth bearing in mind that the context is an Excel CubeSet function, so I'm a little limited in terms of defining my own members in the WITH clause.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a set named `SelectedMembers`, you could use

```
Intersect([MyHierarchy].[Foo].Members, [SelectedMembers])
```

You could of course also code this directly, i. e.

```
Intersect([MyHierarchy].[Foo].Members,
          {
           [MyHierarchy].[Foo].[1],
           [MyHierarchy].[Foo].[2],
           ...
           [MyHierarchy].[Foo].[N]
          }
         )
```

But it might be more convenient to have the set already defined in the cube calculation script - if that is possible.